# Adding Keywords to Ruby syntax highlighting for Notepad++

Tags: ruby, notepad++

I am trying to add `require` and `include` as Ruby keywords for Notepad++, but I am having some trouble.  I modified the langs.model.xml file's ruby language tag as follows:

```xml
<Language name="ruby" ext="rb rbw" commentLine="#">
  <Keywords name="instre1">__FILE__ and def end in or self unless __LINE__
     begin defined? ensure module redo super until BEGIN break do false
     next rescue then when END case else for nil retry true while
     alias class elsif if not return undef yield require include
</Keywords>
```

However, even after updating this `require` and `include` are still not being highlighted like the other keywords.  Can someone please advise?

Comment: I assume you restarted n++ after you did this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Notepad++ provides an interface for this so you should use that rather than modify application files.

Go to **Settings > Style Configurator...**, visit the Ruby tab, choose the INSTRUCTION category, and add the two keywords there so it looks like this:

[image]

With the easier, interface-provided method out of the way, the *real* mistake you made is that you modified the langs.model.xml file, but forgot to rename it such that it overwrites the original lang.xml. The *.model.xml files are default example files.

And with *that* said, you can still modify the langs.xml file so that the new keywords appear for all Notepad++ themes, but make sure to:

- Save in `%AppData%\Notepad++` instead of `%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++` so updating the editor doesn't revert your changes by overwriting program files (assuming `%AppData%` is being used)
- Back up the original langs.xml file, just in case you want to revert to the default

Comment: The changes of the above are probably (depending on what installation option you selected) saved in `C:\Users\<your-name>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\stylers.xml`.

Comment: @Zabba: Keyword definitions are found in langs.xml - stylers.xml defines syntax coloring. Pretty confusing, I know.

Comment: I found that when I added user-defined keywords, they got added to `stylers.xml` - there was no change in `langs.xml`!

Comment: I tried creating a new Style for my current theme but any keywords defined in it don't get changed... even when it's at the default keywords :/ any help?

Comment: Note that you must follow the example of the default keywords and add your new words in lowercase.  It will not match uppercase words, even if the words are used in uppercase in your documents.