# Changing comment line character in Notepad++ langs.xml doesn't work

Tags: notepad++

My company uses # for SQL comments, but the language syntax in Notepad++ for SQL lists the comment line character as --. I want to change my comment line character to #.

Everywhere I've looked recommends editing C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\langs.xml, finding the correct language tag in that file, and changing it to the character I want. The problem is, when I do that nothing changes.

Here's the relevant line copied and pasted from my langs.xml file:

```
<Language name="sql" ext="sql" commentStart="/*" commentEnd="*/" commentLine="#"> ...
```

After making that change, I restared Notepad++ (a couple times), tried opening a new .sql file and applying the language style to it, switched the language to something else and back to SQL. No matter what I do, it still treats -- as the comment character, even though the comment character is set to # in langs.xml.

Is closing/opening Notepad++ not the same as "restarting"? Can I force it to reload the langs.xml file?

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430884/adding-keywords-to-ruby-syntax-highlighting-for-notepad

Comment: @peter Thanks. I tried that before, but the UI for "COMMENT LINE" doesn't have a place where you can edit the comment character. You can only edit the color there >:S

Comment: Or this http://superuser.com/questions/67128/notepad-is-unable-to-load-langs-xml-why :-)

Comment: @peter Thanks again. Changing langs.model.xml was the first thing I tried before I looked into the AppData file. My langs.model.xml file reads the same as the langs.xml file: `<Language name="sql" ext="sql" commentStart="/*" commentEnd="*/" commentLine="#">`...

Comment: In Synwrite app it'd easy to change sql comment char - in lexer dialog.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and updating the langs.xml file in both the AppData and install directories didn't work. I eventually realised that it was using the Settings -> Preferences -> Clouds -> Settings on cloud option, so it was using a config file stored in a Notepad++ folder in the root of my DropBox. I updated that version of the file (running Notepad++ as administrator) and it picked it up on restart of the program.